# Is there any function that allow us to clone mesh or a kind of stamp tool?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am developing a pair of shoes from a standard template, which already has 2 sides of shoes. I have edited the right shoe, but hasn't done the left shoe yet. So, I wonder if there is a way that allows us to copy the shape I have edited in the right shoe to be on the left shoe without manually edit it once again? Both shoes are in the same object, but different vertex groups. Please advise and thank you so much!

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use a mirror modifier, probably with a target for the modifier to indicate the plane of reflection, and to use techniques that allow the mirror modifier to mirror vertex groups: .r and .l suffixes on any groups to be mirrored, and .r and .l versions of vertex groups on the mesh, even though one side's groups are unpopulated.

Comment: @Timaroberts That better?

Comment: Thank you!! will try with all the options you suggested and will let you know!

Answer (score 2):

With your object selected, you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate it, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> as well as a letter denoting your axis (X, Y, Z) to mirror the object along that axis. Foe example to copy a shoe and Mirror it along the Y axis, I would do <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Duplicate) and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> (Mirror on Y)